# TimerTask not running while monitor is in power saving mode

Tags: java, swing

I have extended my java class with java.util.TimerTask. I am setting scheduler at a periodic time like 14:00, 14:30, 15:00 and so on.

If I run scheduler without monitor's power saving mode, its running properly at specified time, while when I set monitor in power saving mode of interval of like 1 minute, then TimerTask is getting delayed or its in sleeping mode.

Later when we use machine in say 1hr, TimerTask will run for 2 times.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, please open a feature request in meta for an animated gif for this.....:)

Comment: What is the relevance of the Swing tag on this question ? I do not find anything Swing related in the question

Comment: Why you using `Timer` from other package(java.util.Timer), if you talking about `Swing`Timer i.e. `javax.swing.Timer`. Firstly learn how to put question, by visiting [Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and [Smart Question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: See [tag:quartz] for more [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/quartz-scheduler/info).